# Preserving PHP Sort after MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a Results page that counts the number of times a specific ID appears in an array.

The code I have performs an array_multisort on the specified element of the array:

```
      $colpubid = array_column($votedpubs, 'pubid');
      $colcount = array_column($votedpubs, 'count');
      array_multisort ( $colcount, SORT_DESC, $colpubid, SORT_ASC, $votedpubs );
```

When I then show this on a page, I get the following:

PubIDCount

BES/262 4
BES/527 3
BES/572 2
BES/158 1
BES/167 1
BES/193 1
BES/238 1

However, when I then lookup the respective elements from a MySQL database, the order is then overwritten, and the results are now sorted based on the order they were retrieved from the DataBase.

[Order after MySQL lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TSfD.png)

This is using the following code:

```
    while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($pubidresult))
    {
       foreach($votedpubs as $thispub )
          {
            if ($row3['PubID'] == $thispub['pubid']) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $thispub['pubid'] . "</td><td>" . $thispub['count'] . "</td><td>" . $row3['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row3['Town'] . "</td></tr>\n";
            }
          }
    }
```

Is there a way I can still perform the MySQL lookup to add in the extra fields (Name & Town) whilst maintaining the sort order of count descending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I can think of means first indexing the `$votedpubs` array by the pubID 
 (using `array_column()`) and then in your `while()` loop from the database query is to add the details into the `$votedpubs` array.

```
$votedpubs = array_column($votedpubs, null, 'pubid');
while ($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($pubidresult))
{
    $votedpubs[$row3['PubID']]['Name'] = $row3['Name'];
    $votedpubs[$row3['PubID']]['Town'] = $row3['Town'];
}

foreach ( $votedpubs as $thispub )  {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $thispub['pubid'] . "</td><td>" . $thispub['count'] . "</td><td>" . $thispub['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $thispub['Town'] . "</td></tr>\n";
}
```